# Map elements of multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to label some values in a DataFrame in Pandas based on the value itself, in-place.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data/extrusion.csv')
# get list of columns that contain thickness
columns = [c  for c in data.columns if 'SDickeIst'.lower() in c.lower()]

# create a function that returns the class based on value
def get_label(ser):
    ser.map(lambda x : x if x == 0 else 1)

df[columns].apply(get_label)
```

I would expect that the apply function takes each column in particular and applies `get_label` on it. In turn, `get_label` gets the `ser` argument as a Series and uses map to map each element != 0 with 1.

Comment: your function does not `return` anything like this

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't return the `ser.map(...)` line from your function?

Comment: can you add some data so others can run / test please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_label` doesn't return anything.

You want to return `ser.map(lambda x : x if x == 0 else 1)`.

```
def get_label(ser):
    return ser.map(lambda x : x if x == 0 else 1)
```

Besides that, `apply` doesn't act in-place, it always returns a new object. Therefore you need

```
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(get_label)
```

But in this simple case, using `DataFrame.where` should be much faster if you are dealing with large DataFrames.

```
df[columns] = df[columns].where(lambda x: x == 0, 1)
```

Comment: This works though I get this error ` SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi That means that `df` is actually a slice/ subset of another DataFrame, right?  That is not clear in the description.

Comment: The error is when running df[columns] = df[columns].apply(get_label) but I think it might be a false positive. Df is not a slice.